# How to preserve formula in whole workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I'm trying to overwrite an existing Excel file.
Then I tried to read in the workbook and use `xlscopy` to copy the original file and make `self.wt_bk` could write something in it.

It seems there is no way to copy formula from original excel file to the new one.

Is there any better way can let me  rewrite some cells in an existed excel file without using `win32com`, because I need to run it on Ubuntu system

Thanks

```
self.rd_bk = xlrd.open_workbook(self.detailed_xls_fname,
                                            formatting_info=True)
self.wt_bk = xlscopy(self.rd_bk)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you will find what you need here.  These packages work in linux as well as windows.

[Working with Excel Files in Python](http://www.python-excel.org/)

I know its not a great answer, but google "python excel".  I don't get paid to be a research assistant.